# How can I move my image tag to the far right of my footer in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, styles, footer

How can i move my image tag to the far right of my footer?
currently the result is: `Random Title {image_logo}` on the left.
The result should be `Random Title                                     {image_logo}` <--- assuming this is a footer.

check out my code below:

```
<LowerFooter className="lower__footer">
        <h2>
           &copy;  <span>Random Title</span>
           <img src = {image_logo} width = '50' height= '50' />
        </h2>

 </LowerFooter>
```

styled component:

```
const LowerFooter = styled.div`
 margin: 0;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: #333333;
 color: white;
 padding: 1rem;
 h2 {
 span {
 color: #FFF;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 }
 @media screen and (min-width: 260px) and (max-width: 450px) {
 h2 {
 span {
 display: block;
 }
 }
 }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex and [`justify-content: space-between`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#setting_flex_item_distribution)

Just move `img` outside the `h2`

```js
<LowerFooter className="lower__footer">
  <h2>
    &copy;  <span>Random Title</span>
  </h2>
  <img src = {image_logo} width = '50' height= '50' />
</LowerFooter>
```

and to the **LowerFooter** just add these styles

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```